# Finding the average

Tags: java

I got this problem that I need to find the average of total salaries for `HourlyEmp` ONLY,
I have a super class `Employee` and two subs already `HourlyEmp` and `OverTimeEmp`
I named the Array Emp[]. `Employee Emp[] = new Employee[7]` < 7 items

Now what I need is like ..if I have more than one Employee who's in `hourlyEmp`
how to get the average of their salaries?
So far I got 2 ideas,but non of em is working somehow

1.

```
'for(int i=0;i<Emp.length;i++) {
      if (Emp[i] instanceof HourlyEmp)

  System.err.println("Average="+(Emp[i].totalsal()/i));'
```

2.

```
double avg=0;
  for(int i=0;i<Emp.length;i++) {
      if (Emp[i] instanceof HourlyEmp)
        avg+=Emp[i].totalsal()/i;
  System.out.println("Average="+avg);
```

I'd appreciate your help :)

Comment: First you need to get summation of all the salaries and then divide that sum by `Emp.length`

Comment: Looks like the math in your second instance is wrong.  To find an average, you need to add all instances then divide by the number of instances.  You're adding the HourlyEmp salaries then dividing by the number of total employees, not the number of HourlyEmp.

Comment: what actually **does** happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only want the average of the HourlyEmp's, you need to keep track of how many there are:

```
double avg=0;
int numHourlies = 0; //number of hourlyEmps you have found so far

for(int i=0; i < Emp.length; i++) 
{
      if (Emp[i] instanceof HourlyEmp)
      {
          //just add up all the values for now ...
          avg += Emp[i].totalsal(); 

          //we have found another HourlyEmp, so we increase our count
          numHourlies ++;
      }
}

// ... and calculate the average by dividing the sum by the number of values
avg /= numHourlies; 

System.out.println("Average="+avg);
```

Answer (score 2):

Option 2 will work if you calculate the average correctly. I.E.

```
a = Get summation of total salary
b = Get a count of how many instances where HourlyEmp
average = a/b
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  public double getAverageSalary 
  {
     double totalSalary = 0;
     double hourlyEmps = 0;
     for(int i=0;i<Emp.length;i++)          
     {
          if (Emp[i] instanceof HourlyEmp)
          {
               totalSalary += Emp[i].salary;
               hourlyEmps++;
          }
     }
     return (totalSalary/ hourlyEmps);
  }
```

Then call this method in your print statement.